# What is the UTI / System Declared Uniform Type Identifier for .mobi files on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

There's a container for epub ['org.idpf.epub-container'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551491-epub), I would like to know the same for .mobi

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/system_declared_uniform_type_identifiers), but it seems lacking.

Comment: I'm not familiar a lot with this framework, but `let type = UTType(filenameExtension: "mobi")`, might be a start? There might be other properties of `UTType` that might worth a look...

Comment: The mime type seems to be : application/x-mobipocket-ebook . May be you could write your own UTI from this

Comment: application/x-mobipocket-ebook did not work.